# Counterexample to finiteness of integral over $R^{n-k}$ for $L^2(R^{n})$-function.

Tags: real-analysis

I have been told that it is false that a function $f\in L^2(R^n)$ will have the property that
$$
g(y)=\int_{R^{n-d}} f(x,y)^2 \mathrm{d}x<\infty,
$$
where $x \in R^{n-d}$ and $ y \in R^{d}$. But that this is false feels intuitively very strange. If this is not the case, how can we  marginalize probability distributions? Or is it not enough to assume square integrability? I have tried coming up with a counterexample, but can't do it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Think of $n=2,d=1.$ The line $\{(x,1):x\in \mathbb R\}$ is a set of measure $0$ in $\mathbb R^2.$ You can take any $f\in L^2(\mathbb R^2)$ and redefine it to be $1$ on this line. Then $g(1)=\infty.$ It's still in $L^2.$

Comment: Thanks, feel stupid that I didn't realize that... but it is a good example, easy go generalize to higher dimensions as well...

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function $f: 
\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ which has value $1$ on the line $y = 0$ but vanishes elsewhere. Note that $f^2 = f$.

Then the integeral $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} f^2 = 0$ since the function vanishes almost everywhere on $\mathbb{R}^2$.

But at $y = 0$, $$g(y) = \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} f(x, 0)^2 \mathrm{d}x = \int_{x \in \mathbb{R}} 1 \ \mathrm{d}x = +\infty$$ since the real line has infinite measure.

The intuition (at least for me) is that at some values of $y$, the function can go crazy, but the function in general is still square integrable (e.g. the function only goes crazy on a set of measure zero...)